# Vaadin, Table generated column value

Tags: vaadin

I use table component and generate column for optiongroup.

[image]

when change `optionGroup's` value, and click the save button, 
the table get the before value - not changed value..

How to get the chaged value ? Not origin value.

here code...

---

```
public class MyTypeColumnGenerator implements ColumnGenerator{

    public Object generateCell( Table source,  Object itemId,  Object columnId) {
        BeanItem<MyType> beanItem = (BeanItem<MyType>)source.getItem(itemId);
        MyType view = beanItem.getBean() ;

        if(view.getValueType().equals(ValueType.Flag)){
                // radio
                OptionGroup opt = new OptionGroup() ;           
                opt.addItem(1) ; // y
                opt.addItem(0) ; // n

                opt.setItemCaption(1, Messages.getString(Messages.Opt_Y));
                opt.setItemCaption(0, Messages.getString(Messages.Opt_N));

                opt.setStyleName("horizontal");

                if(view.getFactorValue() == 0){
                    opt.select(0);
                }else if(view.getFactorValue() == 1){
                    opt.select(1);
                }

                return opt ;

            }else{
                Label label = new Label();
                label.setValue("N/A");
                return label;
            }

    }
}
```

---

```
btnSave.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {

            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {

                Collection<?>  items = table.getItemIds() ;

                for (Object item : items) {
                    Property pName = table.getContainerProperty(item, "name");
                    Property pVal = table.getContainerProperty(item, "value");
}
```

---

`pVal` gets only origin value , not changes value.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a [ValueChangeListener](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/Property.ValueChangeListener.html) to the `OptionGroup` and inside the listener actually set the value on your `MyType view` using something like `view.setValue(...)`.

Your code would then look something like that:

```
OptionGroup opt = new OptionGroup() ;
opt.addValueChangeListener(new Property.ValueChangeListener() { 

    @Override 
    public void valueChange (Property.ValueChangeEvent event){ 
        view.setValue(event.getProperty().getValue());
    } 
});
```